# ¿Como solucionar error en login? Por Favor

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

Hola tengo unos códigos que me funcionan sin ninguno problema cumplen la funcion de login. de la pagina de mi trabajo. he estado intentando crear una nueva herramienta para mis colegas. pero la pagina cuando la envio al servidor me muestra lo siguiente .

**Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/cefglcl/public_html/usuarios/panel.php:35) in /home/cefglcl/public_html/usuarios/panel.php on line 36**

cumple la función de login correctamente pero no quiero que me aparezca esas lineas de error. **me pueden explicar como solucionar por favor.
Gracias**

```
<?php
            include 'serv.php';
            if(isset($_POST['login'])){
                $usuario = $_POST['user'];
                $pw = $_POST['pw'];
                $log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cuestas WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
                if (mysql_num_rows($log)>0) {
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($log);
                    $_SESSION["full_name"] = $row['full_name']; 
                    echo 'Iniciando sesión para '.$_SESSION['full_name'].' <p>';
                    echo '<script> window.location="panel.php"; </script>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");</script>';
                    echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Muestranos tu código por favor...

Comment: sin el código esta difícil saber por que

Comment: Edite la pregunta. Y coloque el código que valida el login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` significa que su script PHP ya ha enviado los headers HTTP, y como tal no puede hacer modificaciones en ellas ahora.

Comprueba que no se envíe NINGÚN contenido antes de llamar a `session_start()`. Mejor aún, simplemente haz que `session_start` sea la primera cosa que haga tu archivo PHP (ponlo al principio, antes de todo HTML, etc.).